# Divide an element in a list with every other element in the list

Tags: python

I would like to take a list of numbers and a value (v) from user and see whether an element divided by another element in the list is equal to v:

e.g.

```
user input:[ 9, 5, 8, 1 ], v = 10,  result: false
user input:[ 2, 4, 5, 7 ], v = 2,    result: 2 and 4
user input: [ 3, 5, 15, 20 ] v = 4, result: 5 and 20
```

below is what I have now:

```
listnum = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
list1 = []
v = int(input("Enter the value of v: "))
listnum = listnum.split()
for num in listnum:
    list1.append(num)
for a in range(len(list1)):
    for b in range(len(list1)):
        if int(list1[a])/int(list1[b]) == v:
            print(list1[b], list1[a])
else:
    print('False')
```

but my output is like:

```
Enter a list of numbers: 2 4 5 7
Enter the value of v: 2
2 4
False
```

how could I adjust the code? Thanks!

Comment: it's bad practice to have your code/function return inconsistent data types...

Comment: Keep in mind an `int` divided by an `int` returns a `float`, and `v` is an `int`, not a `float`.

Comment: also to address the issue at hand, based on what I see your `else` statement is outside its conditional flow

Comment: @gold_cy so should I just leave it like:
if list1[a]/list1[b] == v ?
yea else is outside the conditional flow but i only want it to print false when there is no a,b in the list. so what should i do?

Comment: Do you want to return just one pair of numbers satisfying your condition, or all of them?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay okay got it!

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski i actually want to return all of them, if there is multuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit optimized version:

```py
listnum = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
list1 = []
v = int(input("Enter the value of v: "))
listnum = sorted(list(map(int, listnum.split())), reverse=True)

if(v<2): print("False")
else:
    for i in range(len(listnum)):
        if(listnum[i]%v==0):
            for j in range(i+1, len(listnum)):
                if(listnum[i] == v*listnum[j]):
                    list1.append((listnum[i], listnum[j]))
if(len(list1)==0): print("False")
else: print(list1)
```

Few notes - what I do here:

(1) to make it easier - sort the input array in a descending order. Thanks to this you won't have to run over the whole list twice, but just run over the reminder in the second step (which is still `O(n^2)`, yet it's 2x less operations).

(2) you only need to execute the lookup through reminder, if `v` is a divisor of the bigger number - otherwise you won't find the smaller one anyways.

In total - depending on the input sample - you should see some major performance improvements with this code.

Comment: i wonder if it is necessary to check whether v > listnum[0] if it is sorted in decending order, will it be more efficient?

Comment: I don't check it though... You don't have to do that - it wouldn't be of any use here

Answer (score 1):

Here goes:

```
from itertools import combinations

listnum = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
list1 = []
v = int(input("Enter the value of v: "))
listnum = map(int, listnum.split())

combs = combinations(listnum, 2)
divisors = [(n1, n2) for n1, n2 in combs if n1/n2 == v or n2/n1 == v]

if len(divisors) == 0:
  print(False)
else:
  print(divisors)
```

```
Enter a list of numbers: 3 5 15 20
Enter the value of v: 4
[(5, 20)]
```

Comment: I want the output to be a pair of numbers (a,b) where b/a = v. For example when i input [2,4,3,6] and v = 2, the output is 2,4 and 3,6

Comment: All set. Should be most effective and elegant :-).

Comment: I do agree with one of the comments above though: not recommended to print/return different types based on input. You could return None if not found, or raise an Exception ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
listnum = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
list1 = []
v = int(input("Enter the value of v: "))
listnum = listnum.split()
for num in listnum:
    list1.append(int(num))
found=False
for a in list1:
    for b in list1:
        if a/b == v:
            print(b,a)
            found=True
            break
    if found:
        break
else:
    print('False')
```

**Note** :

1. You can just loop through `list1` without explicitly using the index.
2. You will need a break statement inside the for loop. The associated else part will be executed only if the for loop is not terminated by any break statement.

Please notice that even if there are multiple pairs which can result in producing `v` after division, the above snippet will only print the first pair.

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem, your else condition isn't working as you're expecting.
If what you want to do is print False when no result are found, then you can do something like:

```py
exists = False
for a in range(len(list1)):
    for b in range(len(list1)):
        if int(list1[a])/int(list1[b]) == v:
            print(list1[b], list1[a])
            exists = True
if not exists:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to decide whether an element divided by another element in the list is equal to v, like this way

```
listnum = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
v = int(input("Enter the value of v: "))
listnum = listnum.split()
isDevided=False
for a in range(len(listnum)):
    for b in range(len(listnum)):
        if int(listnum[a])/int(listnum[b]) == v:
            print(listnum[b], listnum[a])
            isDevided=True
if isDevided==False:
    print ("False")
```

Another thing i want to mention that is you are using `list1` as an extra variable and an extra for loop which may decrease the performance, Above code is little bit more optimized, memory and computation wise.

Comment: if i sort listnum and check whether the v is smaller than the listnum[-1], if smaller then proceed, if larger then print('false') will it be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a much more compact way using list comprehensions.  By computing a list of resulting products (number * v) you can use a set to only go throuh the list twice instead of going through it for every single number in it.  This will give you an O(n) complexity instead of O(n^2).

```
numbers  = input("Enter a list of numbers: ")
numbers  = list(map(int,numbers.split(",")))
value    = int(input("Enter the value of v: "))
products = { divisor*value for divisor in numbers }
matches  = [ number for number in numbers if number in products ]
print( ", ".join(f"{prod}/{prod//value}" for prod in matches) or "False")
```

sample runs:

```
Enter a list of numbers: 9,5,8,1
Enter the value of v: 10
False

Enter a list of numbers: 2,4,5,7
Enter the value of v: 2
4/2

Enter a list of numbers: 3,5,15,20
Enter the value of v: 4
20/5

Enter a list of numbers: 5,10,15,30,45
Enter the value of v: 3
15/5, 30/10, 45/15
```

*note that some special cases would need to be adressed (zeroes or repetitions in the list or v == 1) but since your original code didn't bother with those I assumed they are not part of the problem statement*

Here's an even more condensed version:

```
nums = map(int,input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split(","))
v    = int(input("Enter the value of v: "))                
print(*([f"{n}/{n//v}" for s in [set(nums)] for n in s if n//v in s] or "False"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a=input("Enter list of numbers Like 2 4 5 1: ")
v= float(input("Enter the value of v: "))
a= a.split()
b = [int(a[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
b = sorted(b)
final_list = []
for i in b:
    if i not in final_list:
        final_list.append(i)
count = 0
for i in range(len(final_list)):
    for j in final_list[i+1:]:
        if int(j) / int(final_list[i]) == v:
            print(final_list[i], " and ", j)
            count += 1

if count == 0:
    print(False)
```

...